# How can I get the value of a select form element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to populate a select list dropdown in a form with results from an axios call in my action creator. The call populates a  (sub)object in my redux store, then is used to populate the list. It is working fine, but I'm having trouble getting the value of the default list item, i.e. the value of the list item when the onchange event isn't fired.

At the moment the value attribute being controlled by selectedProject seems to have no affect at all. I.E. selectedProject remains an empty string but the first item in the select list is the first in the redux store.

It works fine if the user clicks the dropdown and fires the onChange, but there will be many circumstances where the default value is selected by the user. How can I get it?

Thanks very much for reading!

So far my code is:

```
  const { projects, newProject } = useSelector((state) => state.project)
  const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjects())
  }, [dispatch])

  const handleNavigate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate(`/project/${selectedProject}`)
  }
```

```
return (
    <>
      {projects && (
        <>
          <form onSubmit={handleNavigate}>
            <select
              name='projects'
              id='project-list'
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedProject(e.target.value)}
              value={selectedProject}
            >
              {projects.map((project) => (
                <option key={project._id} value={project.title}>
                  {project.title}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <button>Go!</button>
          </form>
        </>
      )}
</>)
```

Comment: What does determine user selected project from the dropdown menu before you render `projects` as options? Do you have some state from API or does some property of `projects` item have that info?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm struggling to understand what you mean... There are no options before 'projects' is available in the redux store and is populated. The form isn't visible. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Well, your `selectedProject` is an empty string right? And in your list you dont have an item that has `value` as empty string. Based on your code, nothing will be selected. So i am assuming that in your store you have some value that you consider to be the first one that should be assigned to `selectedProject`.

Comment: Or rather, what do you mean with "but there will be many circumstances where the default value is selected by the user"?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing, to be honest. I've not used select dropdowns with react before... I assumed that by setting value as an empty string, an empty value option would be rendered as the initial option before the list is clicked; but that's not the case, the value attribute is ignored (remains an empty string) and the first item in the list (default) is the first in the projects object, when it gets populated.

Comment: Well since `selectedProject` controls your `select` html input, that means what is the value of that state that is the selected value, in your case an empty string. It does not implicitly select the first element from the `projects` array. I will post my answer, as i thought it would be before.

Comment: "but there will be many circumstances where the default value is selected by the user" I mean that the initially selected item, after it's populated from the database will often be the project that the user wants to select.

Comment: In that case, take a look at the code that I posted as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `select` input is being controlled by `selectedProject` that means, what is the value of that state, that is the value of `select` input. In your case initial value of state is an empty string, and that is de facto value.

What you are expecting is for React to automatically select the first element from `projects` list as your fist value. That is not how `select` element and react work. Even aside from React, that is just not how things work.

The correct way of seeing this is to always rely on your state that you assign for `value` prop. Here is the corrected version of your code:

```js
const { projects, newProject } = useSelector((state) => state.project);
const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getProjects());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(projects && projects.length !== 0 && selectedProject !== '') {
    setSelectedProject(projects[0].title)
  }
}, [projects])

const handleNavigate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigate(`/project/${selectedProject}`);
};
```

In the code above, `selectedProject` is set to the first element of the array when the `projects` state is retrieved from redux.

Comment: Thanks :) I used:   useEffect(() => {
    if (projects && projects.length !== 0) {
      setSelectedProject(projects[Object.keys(projects)[0]].title)
    }
  }, [projects])

Comment: It's a shame I need a second useeffect but this solves the issue. Thanks very much

Comment: Yea, in react a lot of things need to be explicit. Cheers. Glad I helped